# Writing data to file in MoSync (Converting MAUtil::String to const char*)

Tags: c++, mosync

I'm trying to write some data to a file in Mosync. This is what I'm doing:

```
String filename = "c:\\hamburger.txt";
MAHandle newfile = maFileOpen (&filename, MA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE);
maFileCreate (newfile);
maFileWrite (newfile, &keyCode, 1);
```

The error occurs at line 2,

```
MAHandle newfile = maFileOpen (&filename, MA_ACCESS_READ_WRITE);
```

when trying to open the address at &filename. It says it can't convert a `MAUtil::String` to a `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `MAUtil::String` into a `const char*` with `.c_str()`.

Thus, instead of `&filename`, I used `filename.c_str()` and it compiled. The entire code still does not work, however.